# Как собрать ArrayList из последних 10 элементов другого ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Как собрать ArrayList из последних 10 элементов другого ArrayList? (В последнем всегда 10 или более элементов). Все элементы в ArrayList - Integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
destArr.addAll(sourceArr.subList(sourceArr.size()-10,sourceArr.size()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getLastTen(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= list.size()-10; i--) {
        l.add(list.get(i));
    }
    return l;
}
```

P.S. если вам нужен универсальный метод который бы вытаскивал с конца ArrayList N количество элементов и добавлял в другой то в метод добавьте параметр типа int и этот параметр передайте в цикл вместо 10

Comment: Посмотрите внимательнее на свой код. Попробуйте передать в качестве аргумента ArrayList из ста элементов. Метод вернет ArrayList  длинной, намного большей чем 10.

Comment: верно, забыл заменить условие в цикле